# express.js not streaming chunked 'text/event-stream' resposne

Tags: node.js, express, event-stream

I'm trying to send a SSE `text/event-stream` response from an express.js end point. My route handler looks like:

```
function openSSE(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream; charset=UTF-8',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
  });

  // support the polyfill
  if (req.headers['x-requested-with'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    res.xhr = null;
  }

  res.write(':' + Array(2049).join('\t') + '\n'); //2kb padding for IE
  res.write('id: '+ lastID +'\n');
  res.write('retry: 2000\n');
  res.write('data: cool connection\n\n');

  console.log("connection added");
  connections.push(res);
}
```

Later I then call:

```
function sendSSE(res, message){
    res.write(message);
    if (res.hasOwnProperty('xhr')) {
        clearTimeout(res.xhr);
        res.xhr = setTimeout(function () {
          res.end();
          removeConnection(res);
        }, 250);
    }
}
```

My browser makes the and holds the request:
[image]

None of the response gets pushed to the browser. None of my events are fired. If I kill the express.js server. The response is suddenly drained and every event hits the browser at once.
[image]

If I update my code to add `res.end()` after the `res.write(message)` line It flushes the stream correctly however it then fallsback to event polling and dosen't stream the response.
[image]

I've tried adding padding to the head of the response like
`res.write(':' + Array(2049).join('\t') + '\n');`
as I've seen from other SO post that can trigger a browser to drain the response.

I suspect this is an issue with express.js because I had been previously using this code with nodes native `http` server and it was working correctly. So I'm wondering if there is some way to bypass express's wrapping of the response object.

Comment: I believe it's a Chrome issue. I literally did this 2 days ago. Changed my `Content-Type` to `text/json` and it magically started working.

Comment: When I get home I'll try `text/event-stream` on the code that I know works.

Comment: I tried in firefox and was seeing same behavior. I"ll try text/json and if that helps.

Comment: @Randy changed my Content-Type ( for the response ) to `text/json`. didn't do anything

Comment: same problem, did you solve this issues? how did you do that? thx.

Comment: Yes. For anyone else seeing this problem. For me it was an issue with my nginx config. There we're upstream rules not being applied to my downstream route.

Comment: @kevzettler hey, I am using a simple express server, and found the same problem. when I do curl /endpoint in command line, it works fine, but when I open a SSE in my client using new EventSource(), has the exactly same issue as you describe, any idea about that? Thx

Comment: @vikingmute all I can say if is if you're behind a proxy or firewall like nginx make sure everythings forwarded correctly

Comment: @kevzettler i'm behind nginx too. How did you configure the 'upstream/downstream forwarding' correctly in nginx?

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I have working in my project.

Server side:

```
router.get('/listen', function (req, res) {
    res.header('transfer-encoding', 'chunked');
    res.set('Content-Type', 'text/json');

    var callback = function (data) {
        console.log('data');
        res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
    };

    //Event listener which calls calback.
    dbdriver.listener.on(name, callback);

    res.socket.on('end', function () {
        //Removes the listener on socket end
        dbdriver.listener.removeListener(name, callback);
    });
});
```

Client side:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", '/listen', true);
xhr.onprogress = function () {
    //responseText contains ALL the data received
    console.log("PROGRESS:", xhr.responseText)
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: may you look here pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506980/sockjs-eventsource-response-has-a-mime-type-text-html-that-is-not-text-eve

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this one too, so after some browsing and reading I solved this issue by setting an extra header to the response object:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
  "Content-Type": "text/event-stream",
  "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
  "Content-Encoding": "none"
});
```

Long story short, when the `EventSource` is negotiating with the server, it is sending an `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br` header which is making `express` to respond with an `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. So there are two solutions for this issue, the first is to add a `Content-Encoding: none` header to the response and the second is to (gzip) compress your response.